# Commonly used solutions for credential caching?

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, credentials

I have question about credential caching in applications. I've searched around on the net for solutions to this problem, but I haven't found anything (which is really surprising, since this is something that every Facebook, Twitter, and email client application has to deal with).

My question is this:

Let's say I'm building some simple Twitter client. I don't want to force the user to enter their password every time. How do most applications tackle this problem? At some point, the client needs to make an API call to authenticate (which includes the password, which is usually in plain text). However, saving the password in plain text somewhere not the correct solution, obviously. So, how do most apps do this safely? I suppose you could cache the password in a file or db if the password is encrypted, but then how do you safely store the decryption key? Or is it generated at runtime using unique information from the client machine as a seed?

Are there any resources (articles, books, etc.) that talk about this? How do most apps handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Single-sign-on (SSO) setups accomplish what you describe typically by providing centralized methods to generate, distribute and validate a key using some type of session ID.

See for one method (used by [StackExchange/StackOverflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/)):

http://openid.org/

Here's something I didn't know: This category of functionality is known as [Federated Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity). For instance, our web system where I work offers (but doesn't require) [Shibboleth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth_%28Internet2%29). See here for a list of options:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Federated_identity

Comment: That helps me understand this a little better, but I still don't see the whole picture. How would one accomplish this without a third party service like OpenID?

Comment: Take a look at the OpenID and Shibboleth specs. They are actually not about a "third party service", but how to tie a credential/authentication service together between multiple sites.